# swfupload doesnot work on IE8, windows 7

Tags: swfupload

swfupload doesnot work on IE8, windows 7, it freezes when uploading.

Comment: to add to the above, it freezes and after 5 mins throws error 2038

Comment: this is the error in the apache error log


[Tue Mar 16 22:27:22 2010] [error] proxy: client x.x.x.x given Content-Length did not match number of body bytes read
[Tue Mar 16 22:27:22 2010] [error] (70014)End of file found: proxy: pass request body failed to 127.0.0.1:5002 (127.0.0.1) from x.x.x.x ()